# Get document URL via Ajax

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, jquery, sharepoint-rest-api, ajax

I have a document library which i am making a Ajax call to:

```
function GetAttachments(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "XXX_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('CM Attachments')/items?$top=5000",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            accept: 'application/json',
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log('All docs below')
            console.log(data)
        },
        error: function(data, error, err, errorCode, errorMessage){
            console.log(data)
            console.log(error)
            console.log(err)
            console.log(errorCode)
            console.log(errorMessage)

        }
    })
}
```

When inspecting the console.log(data) it returns the array in JSON (as specified in my header) But i can't see any URL's related to the document, i have an odata.editLink: and GUID. Is there any way to return the actual URL of this document?

My reason for wanting this is so i can build a "document" list in a custom form i have. I will make a call inside the form to get the attachments and filter where ID is === to formID.

I'd then like to mimic the documents as attachments (will append an icon for each document, and pass the document URL as a href ) so when they are clicked are opened in a new window. Depending on the document type the outcome should either preview the document or download.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `EncodedAbsUrl` field in the select fields. You can add all the fields that you want using the internal column names. So, modify your endpoint as below:

```
url: "XXX_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('CM Attachments')/items?
$select=Title,ID,EncodedAbsUrl&$top=5000",
```

Your full code would be :

```
function GetAttachments(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "XXX/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('CM Attachments')/items?$select=Title,ID,EncodedAbsUrl&$top=5000",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            accept: 'application/json'
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log('All docs below')
            console.log(data)
        },
        error: function(data, error, err, errorCode, errorMessage){
            console.log(data)
            console.log(error)
            console.log(err)
            console.log(errorCode)
            console.log(errorMessage)

        }
    });
}
```

You can bind the Title, ID and the URL field to the UI from the JSON.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Gautam Sheth, this is exactly what i need. Very helpful! Will comment back once implemented in my code!

Answer (score 0):

Use `getfolderbyserverrelativeurl` in your REST call. This will return document URL in response.

Note : This will not get files from the sub folders.

below is the URL that you can use:

`XXX_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('CM Attachments')/items?$top=5000`

OutPut:

[image]

Comment: I guess this will not bring the files which are inside the folders, for that explicitly call the function again

Comment: Yes you are right. It will not bring files from the sub folders. I will mention the same in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Change URL to THIS**

```
url: "test-site/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('CM Attachments')/items?$Select=File/ServerRelativeUrl",
```

Comment: If required add File/Name to get Name if the file